# Detect multiple clicks on a field in React JS

Tags: reactjs, onclick

I want to navigate to a page on clicking a field(say logo) about 5 times like android developer options. I need to code it in ReactJS. Can someone please suggest ways on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can set a clickTime state

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
     ...
     clickTime: 0
  }
}
```

then every time click the logo, set the clickTime +1;

```
onAddClick () {
      this.setState({
         clickTime: this.state.clickTime + 1;
     })
   }
```

when the clickTime equals to 5,navigate to another page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will try it out.